# I need to convert an int value of seconds into a byte depenting on the % value of the original Value

Tags: math, byte, calculation

Let me clarify.
I have an int value of 3600. the timer ticks down. i now have 3000. how much is that compared to the original value but in the scale of a byte (0-255)

so 3600 original value. Now HALF 1800 current value should be half of a byte.

further examples:
600Starting value ---> Current value is now 500. This giving a byte value of about 208.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear dependence:

```
bytevalue = 255 * currentvalue / maxvalue
```

Comment: thanks. it worked :)  i took 255 - that calculation